# Spark Window function, is this a bug in Spark?

Tags: function, apache-spark, pyspark, window

Would someone be able to verify if this is a bug in spark? or am I doing something horrible wrong  with PySpark Window function:

Here is the dataframe:
[image]

Here is the code that I am running to replace the null values in the post_evar8 column:

```
win_mid_desc_ts = Window.partitionBy('post_visid_high_low').orderBy(desc('hit_time_gmt'))
step3win = step3win.withColumn("post_evar8", last(col('post_evar8'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_mid_desc_ts))
step3win.orderBy("visit_page_num").show(100, truncate=False)
```

After running the above code, I get the following results:
[image]

As you can see, the window function updated the null values in post_evar8 column but also replaced 184545857 with 32526519(visit_page_num 26 and 27). Not sure why 184545857 value was replaced.

Here is the same dataframe in JSON(can copy and paste into file)

```
{"post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524187","visit_page_num":1}
{"post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524197","visit_page_num":2}
{"post_evar8":"32526519","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524197","visit_page_num":3}
{"post_evar8":"32526519","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524568","visit_page_num":14}
{"post_evar8":"32526519","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524568","visit_page_num":15}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524599","visit_page_num":18}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524599","visit_page_num":19}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524599","visit_page_num":20}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590524599","visit_page_num":21}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590525921","visit_page_num":26}
{"post_evar8":"184545857","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590525921","visit_page_num":27}
{"post_evar8":"32526519","post_visid_high_low":"3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070","hit_time_gmt":"1590525921","visit_page_num":28}
```

<------------ Updates with more example: ---------------->

Here is an example of unique hit_time_gmt(yellow box) values and the post_evar8 looks correct(red box).
[image]

Here is the example of modifying just the hit_time_gmt(yellow box), so there are 2 similar(1590525922) and 1 unique(1590525921). The post_evar8 value in the middle gets updated from 184545857 to 32526519(red box). This is wrong. 
[image]

In this window function, I just want to update the NULL values in post_evar8(not values already populated). In all cases that that looks correct(green box). hit_time_gmt is just providing the order, why does the value in hit_time_gmt changing the value of post_evar8 (in the red box)?

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not bug.

Because applying `partitionBy` on `post_visid_high_low` column which has same values in your dataframe will treat entire data in dataframe as one partition on that you are applying order by `hit_time_gmt` descending, final result will be ordered like below.

```
>>> df.orderBy(F.desc("hit_time_gmt")).show(truncate=False)
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------+--------------+
|hit_time_gmt|post_evar8|post_visid_high_low                    |visit_page_num|
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------+--------------+
|1590525921  |184545857 |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|26            |
|1590525921  |32526519  |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|28            |
|1590525921  |184545857 |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|27            |
|1590524568  |32526519  |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|15            |
|1590524568  |32526519  |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|14            |
|1590524197  |null      |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|2             |
|1590524197  |32526519  |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|3             |
|1590524187  |null      |3283497750620215155_4391202461688050070|1             |
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------+--------------+
```

from the above result last value of `post_evar8` is `32526519` same value is replace for other values in `post_evar8` column.

Add some more different values in this `post_visid_high_low` column try running same code & check.

Comment: Hi @srinivas, I updated the original message with more examples. The window code that I wrote is designed to only update null values and that does work correctly. I also updated the dataset with more records in the JSON to illustrate the point. Why my concern is that the non-null post_evar8 values are getting updated based on the hit_time_gmt value. This is only used to order the partitioned value.

Comment: try to set - ignorenulls=False, in your code - step3win = step3win.withColumn("post_evar8", last(col('post_evar8'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_mid_desc_ts))